# SSH from host machine Win7 to guest Fedora Machine in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ssh, fedora, sshd

I'm using VirtualBox on Windows 7 to run Fedora 7. I seem to have my SSH on, as `/sbin/service sshd status` tells me. When I do an `/sbin/ifconfig`, I get this:

```
eth0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:CF:5A:0B
       inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I do an `ssh 10.0.2.15` from inside Fedora, and connect back to the guest machine.

When I do an `ipconfig` on my Windows machine, I get this information:

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b42c:a852:a0e8:1636%19
    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
```

When I now use PuTTY, to connect to 192.168.56.1, it says connection refused. Connection to 10.0.2.15 times out.

SSH service is running. I have disabled SELinux. Also, I have allowed ssh as a trusted service in system-configure-securitylevel. I have tried to switch the firewall completely, but it turns back on automatically.

Comment: Did you read VirtualBox manual? What's your virtual machine's network adapter mode? If it's NAT, you need to set up port forwarding.

Comment: If he's trying to ssh into a vm on his own box he doesn't need port forwarding at all.

Comment: John, if you disagree I suggest you too read vbox manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. The manual contains it all. Thanks Bender.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "Linux Guest"
"VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/guestssh/Protocol" TCP
VBoxManage setextradata "Linux Guest"
"VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/guestssh/GuestPort" 22
VBoxManage setextradata "Linux Guest"
"VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/guestssh/HostPort" 2222
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not turning off the firewall if your VM has internet access. Try running `service network restart` (pretty sure it works in Fedora) or simply type `ifdown eth0` then `ifup eth0`. Try connecting to your newly supplied address.

You could also set it statically for example:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Give the `sshd` service a restart too for good measure, then try to connect to `192.168.1.100`.

Comment: I tried service network restart, but get 10.0.2.15 again, to which I failed to connect. When I set ip statically, my internet connection stops working from guest machine. Before I did anything, I tried to pint 192.168.56.1, and it worked perfectly. 10.0.2.15 gives a connection timeout. Can also ping my Windows 7 machine 172.24.1.203 from my Linux guest, when ip is 10.0.2.15, which is dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a simple networking issue.
The IP Networks for your two machines are different.
Try changing your hosted Fedora IP address to `192.168.56.2` and mask `255.255.255.0`.

To confirm this, try to `ping` from one machine to the other without the changes I suggest above. They should be unreachable both-ways.

Comment: Most computers on the internet are in a different network than mine, but I can still connect to them? Even in my own network I have 192.168.x.x and 10.x.x.x mixed, but no problems connecting. (And ping responses may fail for other reasons?)

Answer (score 0):

In your VirtualBox settings for your Fedora 7 VM, set the network adapter to "bridged adapter", and choose your primary ethernet card. This will put the VM on the same subnet as your Windows 7 machine, and Fedora should pick up an IP address from your dhcp server. If you're not using dhcp, configure the Fedora 7 adapter (within Fedora) manually.